# CLI for controlling running process

Tags: python, design-patterns, command-line-interface

I have designed a python program running in the background which monitors a directory and sends me a notification when certain criteria have been met.

I would like to be able to control this program through a CLI. So I would like to be able to write commands which get passed to the background program to change it's behavior.

How can I accomplish this?

Do I write a second program which can launch the background program/send messages to the background program to change parameters?

Comment: This is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. But in brief, your program needs some way to actively listen for messages from your CLI. This could be via a socket, or file with a well-known name that the CLI writes to and your program reads from (either periodically or in response to an OS event that says the file has change), or in response to OS-level signals (which don't carry a payload, but allow for application-specific meanings).

Comment: Even more briefly, read up on interprocess communication (IPC).

Comment: @chepner But using 2 processes that communicate with each other is the way to go? Or are there some alternatives over how this could be designed?

Comment: Yes; it's exactly what you are trying to do. Your background program is one process, your CLI is another.